# Outlook not showing notifications

Tags: notifications, 8.1-oreo, outlook

I am using ms Outlook on my moto g5 plus android 8. My Outlook app does not sure any notifications. It used to but not anymore. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings
Account
Reset account